# Como inserir um array em uma coluna do tipo array do Postgres com o Laravel/Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Eu tenho uma coluna do tipo array do Postgres e estou tentando inser um array nela com o Eloquent, só que está me dando um errado dizendo que a coluna está mal formada.

A minha model está assim:

```
class Leituras extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tb_leituras';
    protected $casts = [
        'ids_autores' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

E no meu controller estou tentanto inserir assim:

```
$leitura = new Leituras();
$leituras->ids_autores = [20,45];
$leituras->save();
```

E dai da o erro:

> "SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  malformed
>   array literal"

Eu já tentei usar a seguinte sintaxe para inserir:

```
$leitura = new Leituras();
$leituras->ids_autores = json_encode([20,45]);
$leituras->save();
```

Mas também não adianta. Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Você entendeu os motivos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `Eloquent` não tem ainda um solução plausível para trabalhar com esse tipo de dado `array` recurso existente no Banco `PostGresql`, ou seja, [ele não suporta isso ainda, que inclusive na sua documentação o campo destinado para operações com](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#columns) `array` são `text` e/ou `json`.

Voltando ainda na explicação a mensagem de erro é porque o dado fica mau formatado com duas aspas, exemplo `""[20,45]""` por causa do `cast` presente na `Model` que para esse tipo de dado não se aplica, ou seja, só é aplicado o `cast` de `array` para campos `text` ou `json` [e para criar as migrations esses dois tipos são bem explicados](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#columns)

Mediante a essa impossibilidade, mude no banco de dados o tipo do campo para um desses dois (`text` ou `json`) e faça do jeito que está fazendo:

- *Model*

  ```
  class Leituras extends Model
  {
      protected $table = 'tb_leituras';
      protected $casts = ['ids_autores' => 'array'];
  }
  ```
- *Inserindo*

  ```
  $leitura = new Leituras();
  $leituras->ids_autores = [20,45];
  $leituras->save();
  ```

que vai funcionar e trabalhar com esses dados em `array` tanto inserindo tanto alterando e retornando um `array` quando assim for pesquisado.

***Um dica:***

***Observação:*** O método `insert` e `update` não passa pela conversão do `cast` `array` e precisa ser convertido, *exemplos*:

***Funciona:***

```
Leitura::insert(['ids_autores' => json_encode([20,45])]);
Leitura::create(['ids_autores' => [20,45]]);   

$leitura = new Leitura();
$leitura->ids_autores = [20,45];
$leitura->save();
```

***Não funciona, precisa utilizar a função*** `json_encode`:

```
Leitura::insert(['ids_autores' => [20,45]])
Leitura::where('id', 1)->update(['ids_autores' => [20,45]]);    
Leitura::where('id', 1)->update(['ids_autores' => [20,45]]);
```

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [Documentation → PostgreSQL 9.1: 8.14. Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html)
- [Laravel migration array type (store array in database column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954424/laravel-migration-array-type-store-array-in-database-column)

Answer (score 1):

Olá você pode usar o método [`insert()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#inserts) e fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$leituras = new Leituras();
        $leituras->insert([
            ['ids_autores' => 20],
            ['ids_autores' => 15],
        ]);
```

Você no caso passa um array associativo, e caso queria inserir outras colunas bastaria passa-las junto.

**Por exemplo:**

```
$leituras = new Leituras();
        $leituras->insert([
            ['ids_autores' => 20, 'coluna_b' => 'valor abc'],
            ['ids_autores' => 15, 'coluna_b' => 'valor bcsd'],
        ]);
```